# java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError in Spring Redis integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I have developed a library (smartconnect-commons) which has integration with redis caching using spring-data-redis. This library can be plugged-in with any application which ever wants to use redis. JUnit tests in that library are successful. No issues so far.

Now I am using above library as a dependency in a Spring boot app. When running the spring boot app, it is failed with application context initialization errors.

```
2017-08-17 10:38:25,118 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -  - Application startup failed
java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.redis.repository.configuration.EnableRedisRepositories.repositoryFactoryBeanClass()
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:612)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:266)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3446)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.<init>(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getConfigurationSource(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:354)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at com.adp.smartconnect.SmartconnectWPInitializer.main(SmartconnectWPInitializer.java:32)
```

Looks like there is a mis match with spring dependency versions, I spent lot of time but could not figure out that. Please see dependency tree of spring boot app.

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ smartconnect-wage-payments-writer ---
[INFO] com.adp.smartconnect:smartconnect-wage-payments-writer:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.adp.smartconnect:smartconnect-config:jar:2.3.42:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-mongo:jar:5.0.999:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.adp.smartconnect:smartconnect-commons:jar:1.0.9-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:1.8.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:1.10.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.adp.avs.domain:cdm:jar:1.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- com.adp.smartconnect:avs-prod-payload:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.adp.smartconnect:smartconnect-mongo-cdm-library-cdm-0.9:jar:1.0.90:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mule.modules:smartconnect-tracking-service-connector-cdm-0.9:jar:1.0.90:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.mule.tools.devkit:mule-devkit-shade:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO] |     \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.11:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-remote_2.11:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.11:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.typesafe:ssl-config-core_2.11:jar:0.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-protobuf_2.11:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty:jar:3.10.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.aeron:aeron-driver:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.aeron:aeron-client:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.agrona:agrona:jar:0.9.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-cluster_2.11:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-testkit_2.11:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.11:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- javax.jms:javax.jms-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.ibm.mq:mqallclient:jar:8.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |     +- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] |        \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:test
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
```

Comment: Please mention your jvm/jdk versions.

Comment: It is 1.8, I found the root cause of this issue, please see my answer below. Thanks Thomas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that spring-data-redis module is not working with spring boot 1.5.3 version. So when I upgraded spring boot version to 1.5.6, issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

> [ERROR] [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication:771] Application startup failed
>   java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.redis.repository.configuration.EnableRedisRepositories.repositoryFactoryBeanClass()

That is because I pull some new code from git, which including code about redis, need the spring-boot-starter-data-redis library.
As the problems given by IDEA, I press alt+enter to auto import this library.

So the problem comes.
I finally click "In IDEA menu File -->Project Structure->Project Settings-->Libraries" 
I found the version here is not the same version in build.gradle.
I guess this version maybe mismatch the other libraries of spring boot.
So I remove this library and try to run gradle command to build the project.
I solved the problem in this way.